# Bad substitution using sh

Tags: sh

I have the following script and I'm getting the following error: **Error: Bad substitution**

```
value="$(cat temp.txt)"
valueWOBegin="$(echo ${value/*====BUILDTYPES====/})"
valueWOEnd="$(echo ${valueWOBegin/====END BUILDTYPES====*/})"
```

This is the temp.txt file

> ====BUILDTYPES==== [BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
> pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
> renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,
> signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug,
> storeFile=/mypath/debug.keystore, storePassword=android,
> keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=jks,
> v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true,
> v1SigningConfigured=false, v2SigningConfigured=false},
> embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={},
> mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
> mManifestPlaceholders={}}, BuildType_Decorated{name=release,
> debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
> pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
> renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true,
> signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={},
> mResValues={},
> mProguardFiles=[/mypath/proguard-rules.pro],
> mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}]
> ====END BUILDTYPES====

Comment: `${variable/string/}` expansion doesn't work on all `sh` implementations. With bash or ksh it would work fine.

Comment: Do I have any alternative using sh? I'm running this script in a container.

Comment: How about `${value##*====BUILDTYPES====}` and `${value%%====END BUILDTYPES====*}`? These are supposed to work on all POSIX shells, but I'm not sure if they are exactly what you're looking for.